# How to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\langle dR_{x_t(e)} U, dR_{x_t(e)} V \rangle$?

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I meet this question when I read the 41th page of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry (as pictures below). I don't know how to deal the red line. What I try :

assume $u_\delta$ is flow of $U$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}  \left[(dR_{x_t(e)})_p U_p \right]  
=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \left[\frac{d}{d\delta}|_{\delta=0}  ~u_\delta(p) x_t(e)
\right ]
=U_pX_e
$$
obviously, $U_p X_e$ is unmeaning. And even I can get $UX$, I still can't get the red line.  I am not familiar with Lie group. I really hope a detailed answer.  Thanks very much.

> [image]
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my old answer, I misinterpreted the text by quite a bit. The following is a somewhat late attempt to fix that, so that any future readers are not confused.

---

The significance of bilinearity of $\langle \,, \, \rangle$ is that the following "product rule" holds:
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\langle dR_{x_t(e)}U, dR_{x_t(e)}V\rangle = \left\langle \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}dR_{x_t(e)}U, dR_{x_0(e)}V \right\rangle + \left\langle dR_{x_0(e)}U, \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}dR_{x_t(e)}V \right\rangle,
$$
where $dR_{x_t(e)}$ on vector fields is defined on page 27. You prove this identity just like you would the first-year calculus product rule, but with the product replaced by the bilinear form $\langle\,,\,\rangle$. (A similar identity holds more generally for bilinear forms on arbitrary vector spaces.)

Since $x_0(e) = e$, the map $R_{x_0(e)}$ is simply the identity, which implies that $dR_{x_0(e)}U=U$ and $dR_{x_0(e)}V=V$. do Carmo proves that
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}dR_{x_t(e)}U = [U, X],
$$
and similarly for $[V, X]$, so the first displayed expression in this answer simplifies to
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\langle dR_{x_t(e)}U, dR_{x_t(e)}V\rangle = \langle [U, X], V \rangle + \langle U, [V, X]\rangle.
$$
Since $\langle dR_{x_t(e)}U, dR_{x_t(e)}V\rangle$ equals $\langle U, V\rangle$, which is independent of $t$, it vanishes when you take the derivative with respect to $t$. The above expression thus implies
$$
0 = \langle [U, X], V \rangle + \langle U, [V, X] \rangle,
$$
which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: I am not sure why you think Do Carmo's notation is bad.  For example, in your description of the Lie bracket, there is no reason to assume $[Y,X]$ means $[Y,X]_e$.  Likewise the inner product need not be at the identity for everything to make sense.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, it is my fault.  In previous page, do Carmo state that $[Y,X]=[Y,X]_e$ when $X,Y$ are left invriant. But I also feel Lee's book is  friendlier for beginner. But the trilogy is too much since I don't have much time. I plan to read the chapter 4 of Lee' Riemannian manifolds  after the do Carmo's chapter 1. Thanks again.

Comment: @JasonDeVito  When $X,Y$ are left invariant, do Carmo show that $[Y,X]=[Y,X]_e$ in previous page. But I don't upload the picture.

Comment: On the previous page, do Carmo states $[Y_e, X_e] = [Y,X]_e$, which is defining the Lie algebra structure on $T_e G$.  This is different from asserting the (false) statement that $[Y,X] = [Y,X]_e$; the left side is a vector field, while the right side is a vector at a single point.